# Verilog getting output as 'x' after running the test branch

Tags: verilog

hello this my first verilog program and I am getting output value as 'x'. Can somebody please explain. Any help would be appreciated thatnks!

```
module circuit (a,b,c,d,o);
input a,b,c,d;
output o;
wire e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n;
not (a,e);
not (b,f);
not (g,c);
not (d,h);
and (i,e,g);
and (j,e,f,c,h);
and (k,a,f,g,h);
and (l,a,c);
and (m,b,g,d);
and (n,b,c,d);
or (o,i);
or (o,j);
or (o,k);
or (o,l);
or (o,m);
or (o,n);
endmodule
module TB_circuit();    
reg a1,b1,c1,d1;
wire o1;
circuit dut(.a(a1),.b(b1),.c(c1),.d(d1),.o(o1));
initial
 begin
a1=1;b1=0;c1=0;d1=0;#100;
$display(o1);
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `or`s are all separately driving `o`. This will cause an X if all the drivers are not sending the same value. Drive `o` with a single `or` gate.

Change:

```
or (o,i);
or (o,j);
or (o,k);
or (o,l);
or (o,m);
or (o,n);
```

To:

```
or (o, i, j, k, l, m, n);
```

---

Also, the ports for `not` need to be swapped.

The first port of all Verilog primitive gates are outputs.

Change:

```
not (a,e);
not (b,f);
not (g,c);
not (d,h);
```

To:

```
not (e,a);
not (f,b);
not (g,c);
not (h,d);
```